# how to generate n rows based on a value in a column in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have following table.

[image]

I need to transform this input as you can see in below output example:

[image]

If you have any ideas please share. Thank you very much!

Comment: ya, it is more close, removed wrong dupes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) for new rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), remove `no` column, get `flag` columns and last create default `RangeIndex`:

```
df1 = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['no'])]
         .drop('no', axis=1)
         .assign(flag=1)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
   id_1  id_2  flag
0     A   100     1
1     A   100     1
2     A   100     1
3     A   200     1
4     A   301     1
5     A   301     1
6     B   122     1
7     B   122     1
8     B   122     1
9     B   122     1
10    B   100     1
```